# Creating custom address locator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geocoding, address

It was 8 years ago when Esri published a famous "Customizing locators in ArcGis 10" whitepaper. They also gave us more than 50000 lines of magic Xml covering US address styles.

I tried to make a rather simple locator style file, removing everything I found unnecessary. After a week or more I had something between 400 and 600 lines of xml file that I pushed to Create Address Locator geoprocessing tool.

I've got "Error code 42". Nothing more. A good sense of black humour.

Do you have any piece of advice how to get more diagnostics?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 has been retired for a while now and locators have changed completely at least once since 10.0. There may not be too much experience with the older technology here. You may need to track the deltas you make and roll back if a test fails (test frequently)

Comment: I have the same problem with creating address locator style for polish addresses. Unluckily some junk sections can't be deleted. I think, it's kind of impossible to make it 400-600 lines. As an apprentice, my task is to correct 'working' locator which is based mainly on US Address locator. I figured out a lot, but still a lot of data is missing. I noticed that error is sometimes caused by something wrong in grammar>spelling section. Copying and pasting it form General locator didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's still actual but:
Have you ever had you locator working with the original "50000 lines of magic Xml" file? 
If Yes and you just need to clean up the file to 400-600 lines, I'd suggest to delete them by small pieces and rebuild the locator after each update. In order to catch the part that you mistakenly deleted.

Comment: No, I gave up with ArcMap story, as Vince correctly mentioned that "Customizing locators" whitepaper no longer matches current ArcGIS versions. It took a while and some management actions to have tele-meetings with guys from Esri Inc.. They told that they plan to implement locators in ArcGIS Pro, let's pray.

Comment: Actually, they have already implemented locators in Pro (if you mean tools to build them). There is a new one Create Locator (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geocoding/create-locator.htm). There is the other approach to create locators without Xml-based styles.

Comment: country_code is interesting but poorly documented. Till 10.5 they were giving away only US locator. I'm in Europe.